# what is the explanation of deque can any one help me?

Tags: c++, stl, deque

I am learning stl and learn how to use all stl containers and i need to knew 
when i have to use deque in my program.
what is the different between deque and other stl containers

Comment: They are *all* slightly different. That's why there is more than one container type.  :-)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/

You can push elements to a deque on both ends.

Example:
You can use a deque as "history".
The oldest items are in front.
Now you have easy access on the newest element and the oldest. (It is good for a undo function)

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque is better IMO.